# System returns me back to the previous page instead of taking to the next one without even clicking 'Next' or 'Back' button

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage See  [WebPage screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEgET.png)

Code

`WebElement whatAirline = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".BaggageFlightDetailsView-airlineField input"));`

`whatAirline.sendKeys("AeroGal (2K)");`

`whatAirline.submit();` //This is kind of  drop down menu list is the COMBOBOX with no class 'select', just class 'input'

`WebElement confirmationCode = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".Input-input"));`
`confirmationCode.sendKeys("test");`
`whatAirline.submit();`

It brings me to the previous page, though 'Next' button on this page becomes enabled!

IMPORTANT:'Next' button is not even a button it just has class -that's all, no other data! `class = ''PagerButtons-button PagerButtons-button--next''

What else i tried? Explicitly wait, click 'Next' as a button (though it is not even a button)
Nothing works ! HELP!

Comment: Please post some code, so that it helps others to answer the specific problem you have

Comment: @NalinAgrawal added. literally nothing is working, i was adding Thread.sleep and waits. I was asking system to click the 'Next' button to get to the next page.

But it brings me back even if i don't write code for button click.
Thanks in advance for taking a look, i started automation just a week ago, my code might be silly as well as explanation.

Comment: Which plugin/platform is this? If this is a webpage, you can try jquery. General idea will be to select the Next element using css selector and then triggering a click on it, immediately after submit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have entered invalid data in any of two fields. So the next button may not be enabled, it automatically clicks enabled back button. Check your inputs. 
Use select class for drop down list. Also use explicit Wait to click next button.

Comment: I did everything as you said - system still brings me to the previous page.

After 3 hours of trying, i realized that something that i'm trying to click is not even the button.
Pls see my update description with IMG.

Comment: Plus no  select class for drop down list, only input as it is combobox!
Data is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The problem that i found was:
Combobox was not holding the value selected in drop-down, just typed it.

System was taking me back because 'Back' button was the only one enabled.
That is why `submit` was taking me back every time.

I added `whatAirline.click();` before `submit` and it worked out!

Please note, that i should have not write `button click` as on top of everything i had no button at all, just an element that looked like a button.